# Compiled Produced Syntax Error in Sencha Touch command line

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I am using sencha touch 2.0.1 I need to build the app using Sencha Command, when using running the comans

sencha app build production

I receive this error.

It seems to me connected to the magnification project.

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here. thanks

```
[INFO] Deploying your application to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vladimir-XXX/build/production
[INFO] Copied sdk/sencha-touch-all.js
[INFO] Copied app.js
[INFO] Copied resources/images
[INFO] Copied resources/icons
[INFO] Copied resources/startup
[INFO] Resolving your application dependencies (file:////Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vladimir-XXX/index.html)
[INFO] Found 31 dependencies. Concatenating all into '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vladimir-XXX/build/production/app.js'
[INFO] Processed sdk/sencha-touch-all.js
[INFO] Minifying sdk/sencha-touch-all.js
[INFO] Processed app.js
[INFO] Minifying app.js
[ERROR] Error: Command failed: 
[ERROR] 2005:25:identifier is a reserved word
[ERROR] 2008:45:missing ; before statement
[ERROR] 2014:21:missing } after property list
[ERROR] 2014:22:syntax error
[ERROR] 2043:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2051:33:syntax error
[ERROR] 2169:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2176:29:syntax error
[ERROR] 2236:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2238:32:syntax error
[ERROR] 2241:13:syntax error
[ERROR] 2242:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2243:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2244:24:syntax error
[ERROR] 2246:9:syntax error
[ERROR] 2311:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2320:31:syntax error
[ERROR] 2378:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2380:34:syntax error
[ERROR] 2382:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2388:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2394:34:syntax error
[ERROR] 2396:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2408:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2410:31:syntax error
[ERROR] 2411:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2417:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2420:31:syntax error
[ERROR] 2421:13:syntax error
[ERROR] 2422:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2423:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2424:24:syntax error
[ERROR] 2426:9:syntax error
[ERROR] 2491:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2493:29:syntax error
[ERROR] 2494:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2500:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2502:12:syntax error
[ERROR] 2503:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2509:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2511:33:syntax error
[ERROR] 2513:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2585:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2587:32:syntax error
[ERROR] 2589:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2605:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2607:32:syntax error
[ERROR] 2609:14:syntax error
[ERROR] 2610:19:syntax error
[ERROR] 2611:19:syntax error
[ERROR] 2612:10:syntax error
[ERROR] 2614:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2616:30:syntax error
[ERROR] 2617:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2618:6:syntax error
[ERROR] 2624:21:syntax error
[ERROR] 2630:6:syntax error
[ERROR] 2632:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2633:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2655:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2657:21:syntax error
[ERROR] 2668:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2670:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2683:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2685:36:syntax error
[ERROR] 2686:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2689:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2691:36:syntax error
[ERROR] 2692:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2695:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2697:12:syntax error
[ERROR] 2698:14:syntax error
[ERROR] 2701:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2703:10:syntax error
[ERROR] 2704:14:syntax error
[ERROR] 2706:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2716:30:syntax error
[ERROR] 2739:15:invalid return
[ERROR] 2740:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2749:39:syntax error
[ERROR] 2769:15:invalid return
[ERROR] 2771:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2780:15:syntax error
[ERROR] 2788:23:invalid return
[ERROR] 2792:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2794:2:syntax error
[ERROR] 1:0:Compilation produced 86 syntax errors.
org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Compilation produced 86 syntax errors.
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor$1.runtimeError(YUICompressor.java:154)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:392)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:337)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:312)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.<init>(JavaScriptCompressor.java:533)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor.main(YUICompressor.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:21)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 2005:25:identifier is a reserved word
[ERROR] 2008:45:missing ; before statement
[ERROR] 2014:21:missing } after property list
[ERROR] 2014:22:syntax error
[ERROR] 2043:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2051:33:syntax error
[ERROR] 2169:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2176:29:syntax error
[ERROR] 2236:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2238:32:syntax error
[ERROR] 2241:13:syntax error
[ERROR] 2242:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2243:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2244:24:syntax error
[ERROR] 2246:9:syntax error
[ERROR] 2311:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2320:31:syntax error
[ERROR] 2378:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2380:34:syntax error
[ERROR] 2382:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2388:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2394:34:syntax error
[ERROR] 2396:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2408:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2410:31:syntax error
[ERROR] 2411:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2417:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2420:31:syntax error
[ERROR] 2421:13:syntax error
[ERROR] 2422:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2423:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2424:24:syntax error
[ERROR] 2426:9:syntax error
[ERROR] 2491:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2493:29:syntax error
[ERROR] 2494:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2500:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2502:12:syntax error
[ERROR] 2503:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2509:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2511:33:syntax error
[ERROR] 2513:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2585:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2587:32:syntax error
[ERROR] 2589:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2605:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2607:32:syntax error
[ERROR] 2609:14:syntax error
[ERROR] 2610:19:syntax error
[ERROR] 2611:19:syntax error
[ERROR] 2612:10:syntax error
[ERROR] 2614:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2616:30:syntax error
[ERROR] 2617:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2618:6:syntax error
[ERROR] 2624:21:syntax error
[ERROR] 2630:6:syntax error
[ERROR] 2632:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2633:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2655:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2657:21:syntax error
[ERROR] 2668:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2670:20:syntax error
[ERROR] 2683:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2685:36:syntax error
[ERROR] 2686:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2689:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2691:36:syntax error
[ERROR] 2692:17:syntax error
[ERROR] 2695:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2697:12:syntax error
[ERROR] 2698:14:syntax error
[ERROR] 2701:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2703:10:syntax error
[ERROR] 2704:14:syntax error
[ERROR] 2706:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2716:30:syntax error
[ERROR] 2739:15:invalid return
[ERROR] 2740:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2749:39:syntax error
[ERROR] 2769:15:invalid return
[ERROR] 2771:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2780:15:syntax error
[ERROR] 2788:23:invalid return
[ERROR] 2792:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 2794:2:syntax error
[ERROR] 1:0:Compilation produced 86 syntax errors.
org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Compilation produced 86 syntax errors.
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor$1.runtimeError(YUICompressor.java:154)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:392)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:337)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:312)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.<init>(JavaScriptCompressor.java:533)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor.main(YUICompressor.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:21)
[INFO] Minified sdk/sencha-touch-all.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the error message is pretty obvious: there are JavaScript syntax errors being encountered, presumably from your code.

Run your code through JSLint/JSHint to find some of these problems. If you have a large project, then a tool like [LintRoller](http://arthurakay.github.com/LintRoller/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a `debugger` tag in the source code.
So the minification was not able to proceed.